# How to capture error message from executed command?

Tags: bash, scripting, string

I was tasked to create an automated server hardening script and one thing that they need is a report of all the output of each command executed. I want to store the error message inside a string and append it in a text file.

Let's say I ran this command:

```
/sbin/modprobe -n -v hfsplus
```

The output of running this in my machine would be:

```
FATAL: Module hfsplus not found
```

How can I store that error message inside a string? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I tried running this command:

    var=$(/sbin/modprobe -n -v hfsplush)

And then displaying it:

    $var

But it still doesn't capture the error message inside the string.

Answer (score 53):

you can do it by redirecting errors command:

```
/sbin/modprobe -n -v hfsplus 2> fileName
```

as a script

```
#!/bin/bash
errormessage=$( /sbin/modprobe -n -v hfsplus 2>&1)
echo $errormessage
```

or

```
 #!/bin/bash
errormessage=`/sbin/modprobe -n -v hfsplus 2>&1 `
echo $errormessage
```

if you want to append the error use `>>` instead of `>`

Make sure to use `2>&1` and not `2> &1` to avoid the error
"syntax error near unexpected token `&'"

Comment: I've tried that approach and it stores it DIRECTLY in the text file. I want it to store inside a string first so I can format the contents easily.

Comment: @MiguelRoque see updates

Comment: I tried putting the output inside a HEREDOC and it worked also. Thanks a lot @Networker!

Comment: Someone reverted the edit I did, because I had a "syntax error near &" and removed the space after >. A justification would have been nice.

Comment: I tried to edit because : Make sure to use 2>&1 and not 2> &1 to avoid the error "syntax error near unexpected token `&'"

Answer (score 19):

Simply to store as a string in bash script:

```
X=`/sbin/modprobe -n -v hfsplus 2>&1`
echo $X
```

This can be a bit better as you will see messages when command is executed:

```
TMP=$(mktemp)
/sbin/modprobe -n -v hfsplus 2>&1 | tee $TMP
OUTPUT=$(cat $TMP)
echo $OUTPUT
rm $TMP
```

Comment: Always use $(command) instead of backticks for command substitution. It is better :)

Comment: I know it is better (I've had less issues using $()), but why is that?

Comment: @KolonUK For one thing, you can nest them.

Answer (score 10):

To return the error message in a variable, simply;

```
error=$(/sbin/modprobe -n -v hfsplus 2>&1 1>/dev/null)

echo $error
```

Comment: That's the answer, since the other ones would append standard output to the variable. Usually, you want to know if the message comes from a error or not and that's perfect. For example, to throw a warning or to handle a bad situation in a script.

Answer (score 6):

Newer bash versions (I.e. bash 4.1+):

```
$ msg=$(ls -la nofile 2>&1)
$ echo $msg
ls: cannot access nofile: No such file or directory
$
```

Answer (score 4):

To append to a file use `/sbin/modprobe -n -v hfsplus 2>> filename`

Answer (score 4):

I capture error like this

```
. ${file} 2>&1 | {
  read -d "\0" -t 0.01 error
    [ -z "$error" ] || log_warn Load completion ${file} failed: "\n${error}"
}
```

if source failed, I will capture the error and log it.log_warn is just a simple function.

BTW, I use this in my [dotfiles](https://github.com/wenerme/dotfiles/tree/master/.bashrc.d)